# Maclaurin Series: Complex Analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, taylor-expansion

Question: Use the representation $\sin z = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$, $|z|<\infty$ to write the Maclaurin series for the function $f(z) = \sin z^2$ and point out how it follows that $f^{(4n)}(0) = 0$ and $f^{(2n+1)}(0) = 0$  ($n = 0, 1, 2, ...$).

Attempt at solution: The first part of this problem is pretty straightforward: replace $z$ with $z^2$ in the Maclaurin representation of $\sin z$, so that
$\sin z^2 = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{z^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}$, $|z|<\infty$.
Simple enough. However, I have no idea how to go about the second part of the problem. My first instinct was to write the expanded form of the series as such:
$\sin z^2 = z^2 - \frac{z^6}{3!} + \frac{z^{10}}{5!} - \frac{z^{14}}{7!} + ...$.
The patterns I see are that the powers of each term increase by $4$ each time starting at $2$, and the factorials are sequential odd numbers, starting at $1!$. However, I do not know how to link this back to the second part of the problem.

Comment: Do you know that the Taylor series around a point is unique? Do you know the formula for the coefficients of the Taylor series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the powers on $z$ are of the form $4n+2$ and thus $f^{(4n+2)}$ will have a constant term in the front followed by terms containing $z$ which disappear when the derivative is evaluated at $z=0$. All other derivatives of $f(z)=\sin{z^2}$ will only contain terms with $z$ and thus equal $0$ when $z=0$